# Fetch JSON Object via Android-Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using volley library for httprequest as follows. I am running the code in the debug code and putting break point to see json object but it neither returns json object nor show error messages.

```
private void productAll() {
   JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                Config.PRODUCT_URL,null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                        try {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + jsonObject.getString("imagePath"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        catch(JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to parse data: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to fetch data: " + volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you enqueueing the request?

`Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request);`

However, with Volley it's advisable to have one queue instance per app. You can consult the official documentation & tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html).

Comment: no I am not actually, it gives me an error because my class Extends from `AppCompatActivity`. I do not know how to handle that?

Comment: You have to enqueue the request in order to be processed. What is the actual error?